# Hibernate Entity sort column configuration

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate

Is there a Hibernate configuration (hopefully an annotation on a classes mapped @Column field) that would let me sort a collection of entities associated with the loaded entity by a given column of that entity when a session.load(Entity.class, Id) is called?

For example if I had an EntityA that contained a OneToMany association to an EntityB.

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
    private Set<EntityB> headlines = new TreeSet<Entity>();

}
```

I want EntityB to be sorted in the Set that is returned from Hibernate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[session.load()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Session.html) loads a single entity instance. No sorting is involved.

**Update** (based on question edit):

`@OrderBy("column_name")` can be used to sort collection elements within entity by given column; however that only makes sense for collections that maintain their order (e.g. List, not Set):

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
@OrderBy("name")
private List<EntityB> headlines = new ArrayList<Entity>();
```

Comment: I used a SortedSet and used the @Sort annotation (but someone on stackoverflow thought that was a bad answer, any idea why?)

Comment: @Dougnukem I realize this is an old post but here's hoping this helps someone else: `@Sort` is a 'bad' idea because the ordering happens on the application server. With `@OrderBy` the list is sorted on the database server. Generally it is preferred to let the database handle sorting because it is one of its strengths.

Answer (score 1):

Session.load does not load a list, only a single object.

You can sort a list of entities when you retrieve them from the database by using the addOrder() method on the criteria.

If you have a parent class with a list of children, you can order the children with the @OrderBy annotation (see [Hibernate Annotations - Collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association-collections)

Answer (score 1):

I used @Sort and a SortedSet collection to map my association which required that my Entity implement Comparable interface (int compareTo(T) method).

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Sort(type=SortType.NATURAL)    
private SortedSet<Entity> headlines = new TreeSet<Entity>();
```

Comment: any reason why this is a bad solution?

Comment: If `headlines` is created in memory, this is not a bad solution. Every scenario is different but, in general, if it is loaded from a database you'd want to let the database do the sort for you for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can select ordering only on collection level (@OrderBy) or throug hql or criteria api.